# Jquery не получается сделать адаптивный div при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu_toggle_control").on('click',function(){
        $("#left-menu").animate({
            width: 'toggle',
            opacity: 'toggle'   
        }, 'slow');

    resizeMain();
    });



    function resizeMain(){
    if($('#left-menu').css('display')!=='none'){
        $("#main").css("width",($(window).outerWidth()-$("#left-menu").outerWidth())+"px");
    }
    else{
        $("#main").css("width",($(window).outerWidth())+"px");
    };

    };
    $(window).load(function(){
    resizeMain();
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
    resizeMain();
    });
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки левое меню скрывалось и *main* занимал всю ширину, а при обратном нажатии кнопки появлялось левое меню и *main* занимал оставшуюся ширину окна?

Comment: а что такое «обратное нажатие кнопки»? «повторное»?

Comment: А где пример с неправильной работой можно увидеть?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так к примеру:

```
<style>
    #sidebar {
      width: 210px;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      background: #2a3542;
     }

     #main-content {
      margin-left: 210px;
     }
    .navbar{
        cursor:pointer;
        color:red;
    }
</style>
<div class="navbar">Click Here To Toggle</div>
<div id="sidebar">sidebar content here</div>
<section id="main-content">main page content here</section>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.navbar').on('click', function(){
            $('#sidebar').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
            $('#main-content').animate({
                'margin-left' : $('#main-content').css('margin-left') == '0px' ? '210px' : '0px'
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Можно глянуть в действии на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borodatych/d5qqqthm/)